# Use foreach loop within formulas?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I was trying to use the `\foreach` loop from tikz to shorten a list of formlas. Within each formula, only an index changes, so I thought I could use `foreach` within an `align` environment write each formula on one line. This does not work unless I remove the linebreaks `\\` after `r^2`. Is there a way to use line breaks within `foreach`?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    % for foreach
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{ (x_\i - x_c)^2 + (y_\i - y_c)^2 =  r^2  \\ }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\foreach` cannot straddle alignment cells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a sledgehammer for a simple task with copy-paste. Anyway, this can't work for at least two reasons: the code of every `\foreach` cycle is executed in a group and `align` builds a table the same as `tabular`, so each cell forms a group as well.

Even if `\foreach` didn't enclose each cycle in a group, it couldn't straddle cells.

You *could* do

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}    % for foreach
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\aligntemp}{}

\begin{document}

\gdef\aligntemp{}%
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{%
  \xappto\aligntemp{(x_\i - x_c)^2 + (y_\i - y_c)^2 &=  r^2  \noexpand\\ }%
}%
\begin{align*}
\aligntemp
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it worth the trouble? Note that “risky” commands such as `\text` should be prefixed by `\noexpand` (not only `\text`, of course). Also, `\\` at the end would produce an undesired line.

Here's a better version:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}                 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mathrepeat}{O{align*}mm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq { #3 }
   }
  \begin{#1}\seq_use:Nn \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq { \\ }\end{#1}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mathrepeat{1,2,3}{
 (x_{#1} - x_c)^2 + (y_{#1} - y_c)^2 &=  r^2
}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

The optional argument to `\mathrepeat` is the name of the environment to use; for instance `\mathrepeat[align]{1,2,3}{...}` would number the lines.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mathrepeat}{O{align*}mm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq { #3 }
   }
  \begin{#1}\seq_use:Nn \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq { \\ }\end{#1}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_flawr_mathrepeat_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mathrepeat[align]{1,2,3}{
 (x_{#1} - x_c)^2 + (y_{#1} - y_c)^2 &=  r^2 \label{myeqs#1}
}

We see in \eqref{myeqs1}--\eqref{myeqs3} that \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course like this you also get the problem that the last line has `\\ `.

Comment: Great, thank you very much=) The reason I don't want to copy paste it, is that I was told that I cannot just use a general index $i$ for some reason, but have to write each equation out (not my decision...), so that saves quite some hassle.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, that's true. But it was just to give an example how the code should be written, which is already a stopper, in my opinion.

Comment: @flawr I added a higher level set of macros that you might enjoy more.

Comment: Wow that is even a better solution for my purpose, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    % for foreach
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}{\expandafter\xdef\csname eq\i\endcsname{%
 (x_\i - x_c)^2 + (y_\i - y_c)^2 =  r^2}}
\begin{align*}
\csname eq1\endcsname\\
\csname eq2\endcsname\\
\csname eq3\endcsname
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]